# godot multiplayer not working on 1 computer

Tags: 2d, godot, multiplayer, gdscript

I'm trying to test my godot multiplayer and I need to do it from 1 computer, but the thing is it doesn't work (obviously) when I run it with two godot applications open I get these errors: (error from server joiner) `E 0:00:02:0306   _send_sync: Condition "!sync || !sync->get_replication_config_ptr() || !_has_authority(sync)" is true. Continuing. <C++ Source>   modules/multiplayer/scene_replication_interface.cpp:812 @ _send_sync()`  (error from server hoster)`E 0:00:07:0261   _send_sync: Condition "!sync || !sync->get_replication_config_ptr() || !_has_authority(sync)" is true. Continuing. <C++ Source>   modules/multiplayer/scene_replication_interface.cpp:812 @ _send_sync()`  both of these errors have delta variations where it's `_send_delta` instead all I can offer is my code:

```
extends Node2D


var peer =  ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
@export var player_scene: PackedScene
@onready var menu = $CanvasLayer


func _on_host_pressed():
    menu.hide()
    peer.create_server(8120)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer
    multiplayer.peer_connected.connect(add_player)
    add_player(multiplayer.get_unique_id())


func add_player(id):
    var player = player_scene.instantiate()
    player.name = str(id)
    add_child(player)


func _on_join_pressed():
    menu.hide()
    peer.create_client("localhost",8120)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer
```

Comment: is nobody gonna awnser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has been fixed, I wasn't using a debug feature. (I had to turn on multiple instances of the game running at the same time through debug menu)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).